# Create an index for OwnesOne navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Let's see the next example:

```
public class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Client Client { get; set; }
}

public class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have the next part of entity configuration:

```
builder.OwnsOne(x => x.Client, client =>
{
    client.Property(x => x.Id).IsRequired(false);
    client.Property(x => x.Name).IsRequired(false);
});
```

If we apply the migrations to a DB, we will see a single table `Blogs` with a column `Client_Id`.

Now I want to create an index for this column. I added the next line to the entity configuration.

```
builder.HasIndex(x => x.Client.Id);
```

And if you are trying to create a migration you will see the next error:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
---> System.ArgumentException: The properties expression 'x => Convert(x.Client.Id, Object)' is not valid.
The expression should represent a simple property access: 't => t.MyProperty'.
When specifying multiple properties use an anonymous type: 't => new { t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }'.
```

Is it possible to create the index using entity configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Owned types are configured separately for each owner type using the fluent API of the ownership builders.

You can create index the same way you configure properties, e.g.

```
builder.OwnsOne(x => x.Client, client =>
{
    client.Property(x => x.Id).IsRequired(false);
    client.Property(x => x.Name).IsRequired(false);

    client.HasIndex(x => x.Id); // <--
});
```

The only potential problem would be if you need to create composite index with fields from both owner and owned type, which I believe is not possible currently (current EF Core limitation).